# undefined method `fetch_value' for nil:NilClass when using Roo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roo

I am trying to use Roo to import data from an Excel spreadsheet into a table (data_points) in a Rails app.

I am getting the error:

```
undefined method `fetch_value' for nil:NilClass
```

and that error references my data_point.rb file at line (see below for full code excerpt):

```
data_point.save!
```

The "Application Trace" says:

```
app/models/data_point.rb:29:in `block in import'
app/models/data_point.rb:19:in `import'
app/controllers/data_points_controller.rb:65:in `import'
```

I am puzzled by this because a "find all" in my entire app shows no instance of fetch_value

Here is the other code in my app:

In my model, data_point.rb:

```
class DataPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :annual_income, :income_percentile, :years_education

def initialize(annual_income, income_percentile, years_education)
    @annual_income = annual_income
    @income_percentile = income_percentile
    @years_education = years_education
end

def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..11).each do |i| 
        annual_income = spreadsheet.cell(i, 'A')
        income_percentile = spreadsheet.cell(i, 'B')
        years_education = spreadsheet.cell(i, 'C')
        data_point = DataPoint.new(annual_income, income_percentile, years_education)
        data_point.save!
    end
end 

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
end
end
```

In my controller, data_points_controller.rb I have added, in addition to the standard rails framework:

```
def import
    DataPoint.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Data points imported."
end
```

In the Excel file I'm using, the header row has column names that are exactly the same as the 3 attributes noted above for DataPoints: annual_income, income_percentile, years_education

P.s. I have already watched RailsCast 396: Importing CSV and Excel, and read the comments many times.  I think I am struggling with translating the example code to Rails 4 and / or my assignment of individual attributes (vs. the approach used in the RailsCast).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `fetch_value` is an ActiveRecord method. It's one of the things that gets used when you do `model.save!` As for why you're getting, I'm not sure on that. The only thing I can see that uses `fetch_value` is a method calls `_read_attribute` which does `@attributes.fetch_value` So `@attributes` is `nil`. It might be your `DataPoint.new(annual_income, income_percentile, years_education)`. Try `DataPoint.new(annual_income: annual_income, etc...)`

Comment: Thanks, when I try data_point = DataPoint.new(annual_income: annual_income, income_percentile: income_percentile, years_education: years_education) I get an error wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)...  is something about my syntax wrong that Rails is reading this as 1 rather than 3 attributes?

Comment: It is interpreting it as a hash of attributes, which it should be doing. Is your `new` method setup so it takes each attribute as an argument rather than `.new({attributes hash}, {options hash})`? Nevermind, I see your initialize method overwrites it.

Comment: Okay, see see what the initialize method does here http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new/class You're overwriting it so everything it does is not done any more. (click view source right after the examples, before the comments)

Comment: Thanks, when I delete the initialize method I am able to create 10 instances of DataPoint (as expected) -- my use of initialize was a vestige of when I was practicing in a .rb file, no rails app.  However, I now have the problem that all the attributes of each DataPoint are nil.  Even when I use the syntax you suggest above, I cannot set the values.  Please let me know if you have any idea what might be wrong.  Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm, `.new` would give an error if you set an attribute does not exist, and `.save!` should give an error if it fails. Is there no chance that the values it is getting are `nil` or nothing? If you change the `.new(etc..)` to `DataPoint.new(annual_income: '10', income_percentile: '5', years_education: '4')` does that work?

Comment: I thought that explicitly specifying the values should work, too, but oddly it does not.  The same Excel file can be read just fine with the practice.rb file...unclear what's different "inside the rails app"..

Comment: That is very odd. Does your server console show any SQL being executed?

Comment: Yes, it does:    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "data_points" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-06-02 19:39:43.856012"], ["updated_at", "2015-06-02 19:39:43.856012"]]
   (2.3ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction

Comment: So it is definitely not passing the values. If you add `puts data_point.inspect` after `new`, but before `save` does it show `nil`s or actual values?

Comment: nils     #<DataPoint id: nil, annual_income: nil, income_percentile: nil, years_education: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction

Comment: I think it's the `attr_accessor :annual_income, :income_percentile, :years_education` does it work if you remove this?

Comment: YES!  That worked!  THANK YOU!  How did you know that / why did that work?

Comment: That was the only difference between your model, and one I had, so I tried adding it to one of my attributes, and... `nil`. Because you're connecting to the database, all attributes are already accessible. Anything you make an `attr_accessible` is extra data you want to attach to that model instance, but don't want in the database. This is of course a problem if you use the same name for both.

Comment: Glad to help. I'll put this in an answer so you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you had some leftovers from your non rails practice, as we found in the comments. Notably, the overwritten `initialize` method, and the `attr_accessor` for each of the attributes. Removing them (and fixing the `DataPoint.new()` for the correct format) was all that was needed.

Answer (score 24):

I ran into a similar error also when trying to use Active Record with a legacy database.  The problem for me was related to the fact that one of the columns of my database was named 'class,' which caused all sorts of things to fail.  I renamed the column in the legacy database and everything worked fine.

Moral of the story- check the column names for any reserved words.

Comment: Did you find a solution or just renamed the column?

Comment: I renamed the column.  Edit original answer to make this explicit

Comment: Exactly what happened to me.

Answer (score 8):

This is the problem encountered yesterday, the reason is I defined a Database field with name `class`, which is a reserved word for the Ruby language. It caused the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `def initialize()` method

Comment: Please add an explanation why this will solve the problem, that will make your answer a lot more helpful.

Comment: This was it for me. I was upgrading a PORO into an active record object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not restricted to delete the `initialize` method for some reason, instead of removing it, you can try to add a `super` call like so:

```
def initialize(annual_income, income_percentile, years_education)
  super()

  @annual_income = annual_income
  @income_percentile = income_percentile
  @years_education = years_education
end
```

**Sources:**

- More info about `super` can be found [here](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/09/ruby-super-keyword/).