# Ruby on Rails: Fetch_values Rollback error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have upgraded my Ruby to 2.5 and after rectifying many dependency issues, I'm stuck at a place.
There is save method being called which saves the records, but somehow it do not works now and shows following error:

```
500 Internal Error
undefined method 'fetch_value' for #<Hash:0*0007e589e>
Did you mean fetch_values
             each_value:
```

Earlier the same `.save` was working perfectly fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602250/undefined-method-fetch-value-for-nilnilclass-when-using-roo

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the same exception before. In my case, some ActiveRecord models were marshaled via `Marshal::dump` and saved as binary stream. Then, Ruby and Rails were upgraded.

Afterwards, calling `Marshal::load` on the marshaled copies would retrieve them and `object.class` would show the right model's name, but accessing any attribute within would throw the same exception.

I had to clear the marshaled copies and generate new ones.